# What does `L:` mean in `"injectionSelector": "L:markup.fenced_code.block.markdown"`?

Tags: visual-studio-code, textmate, tmlanguage

At https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-fenced-code-block-grammar-injection-example/blob/master/syntaxes/codeblock.json

The extra grammar is injected into the scope `markup.fenced_code.block.markdown`

However `L:markup.fenced_code.block.markdown` is used. What does `L:` mean in this case? Is it a special syntax for scope selector? I cannot find any related info in https://manual.macromates.com/en/scope_selectors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `L:` specifies injection priority. It means that the rule will be injected to the left of any existing rules in the same scope, i.e. it will be applied before the other rules

Comment: What's the difference between `R:` & no prefix. If there is no prefix, the injected rules are appended to the right, isn't that the same as `R:`?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/html/syntaxes/html.tmLanguage.json#L12